# Is there a way to update the firmware through internet that works for esp32?

Tags: arduino, firmware, ota, esp32

We can update the firmware wirelessly using the OTA updates. But for updating the firmware, the esp32 device needs to be on a local network.
Is there any way or source to update the firmware of the device which is not on the local network?

Comment: No network means no OTA. No network also means no internet. If it is not connected to a network what is it connected to?

Comment: @Gerhard The title of the question is "Is there a way to update the firmware through internet...". I think you are misunderstanding the question. I believe the OP is asking if firmware can be updated over the internet instead of a LAN, which it definitely can. The firmware just needs to be hosted on a web server and the firmware needs to pull from that server.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to update ESP32 firmware over the internet without any additional update server (with public and static IP address) and without port forwarding. It is based on Husarnet p2p VPN service.

The instruction is here: https://docs.husarnet.com/blog/internet-ota-esp32

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ESP32 OTA works very similar to ESP8266 which I have used.  This can be accomplished in at least two ways.

This link: http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.1.0/doc/ota_updates/ota_updates.html

gives details on using the browser to deploy the update to the device.  You would need to forward your port 80 traffic from your public IP to your internal device IP address.  Then you can access your ESP through the browser and your public IP address.  The better option is to publish your updated firmware to an externally available HTTP server and change your ESP OTA codde to check that external server for updates.  This method is detailed in the "HTTP Server" section of the above document.  This is just general guidance to the general question you asked.  I believe the solutions above would work, but I have not tried them myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. OTA has no requirement of the device being on a local network. You just need to host your firmware .bin file on a web server, then have the ESP32 connect to the server and send a GET request. Espressif's example project for OTA is pretty good, but I'm assuming you're using the ESP32 Arduino libraries and not the ESP-IDF.

I'm guessing you're using [this.](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/OTAWebUpdate/OTAWebUpdate.md) I'd take a look at the AWS OTA example which I believe is one of the standard ESP32 Arduino examples. It's under Examples, Examples for SparkFun ESP32 Thing, Update, AWS_S3_OTA_Update. It looks like it allows you to OTA from an Amazon Web Services hosted server, which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: so it is possible to trigger it from the ESP? Most of the examples I have seen trigger it from an IDE or command line on the machine  hosting the firmware. I have a scenario where I would like the device itself to check a remote address for updates.

Comment: @Scott Yeah, you can totally have the esp32 initiate the update. I am developing a device right now where OTA updates are triggered base on a bluetooth command from a phone. The device checks the server for the new firmware file when it receives the BLE command. Having the device constantly (or occasionally) check the server for a new file would be implemented in a very similar way. That is what the ESP-IDF OTA examples do: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/release/v3.1/examples/system/ota

Comment: ok, thought so. I think I have a lib link that shows an example of it now also. I would have the user trigger it either on the device or from a web page interface. Now I'm trying to figure out how to trigger an update for the EasyVR when connected on serial.

Comment: @Scott I'm not familiar with EasyVr. I did a quick search on it though. If the EasyVr has its own separate firmware from the ESP32, you should be able to download the EasyVr firmware from the web onto the ESP32 and write the flash of the EasyVr with the new firmware. So you wouldn't really be able to use the built in ESP32 OTA functions for that, but it would be simply downloading a file and directly loading that onto the EasyVr. If there is no separate firmware (the ESP32 is driving the EasyVr completely) then it would just be a standard OTA of the ESP32.

Comment: I hope so because I'm still trying to figure out from their documentation how to trigger it's sound programming mode from another micro controller. It looks like the triggering of the on-board programming modes for voice queues can be done over a simple tx/rx though but I'll have to write code that can be triggered from a web page to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an app that fetches the update file from the internet or elsewhere then transfer the file via BLE to the ESP32. In this case, the ESP32 will need to be connected to the phone via BLE only (no WIFI needed).

Here is the example [Arduino](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino) code for the ESP32 and the [Android app](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Android) code